# Making 2D arrays in Verilog

Tags: arrays, verilog

How do I create an 2D array in Verilog? To be precise, I wanted a 32x100 matrix. Then, how do I define the values of each position of this array?
I tried some stuff I found on the web, but my code needs to be synthesised , simulating is not enought.

Thanks

My attempt so far (I'm new to verilog)

```
module top(
input a
);

integer i;
reg [31:0] arr[0:99];

initial begin
    for(i=0;i<100;i=i+1) begin
        assign arr[i] = 22;
    end
end

endmodule
```

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Comment: There, I edited it. That useless input is because the software I'm using wouldn't allow no inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `assign` within an `initial` block or `always` bock. It is procedural assign a simulation feature scheduled for depletion ([IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) C.4 *Constructs identified for deprecation*).

I'm guessing you are targeting FPGA, you can initialize the array with:

```
initial begin
    for(i=0;i<100;i=i+1) begin
        arr[i] = 22;
    end
end
```

IC design ignore `initial` the code would have to go into the reset condition of an `always` block. Alternatively if it is a ROM you can use a generate block:

```
genvar i;
generate
    for(i=0;i<100;i=i+1) begin
        assign arr[i] = 22;
    end
endgenerate
```